# Datos de distintos resultados en una misma fila

Tags: php, html, mysql

De primeras quiero pedir perdón por el título si es un poco confuso, pero no sabía de qué forma resumir lo que quiero hacer. El caso es que tengo una base de datos de clientes y necesito mostrar resultados por meses y agrupar por Hombres y Mujeres, el problema es que al extraer los datos y añadirlos a una tabla, no encuentro la forma de hacer que queden los resultados en la misma fila, sin dar saltos.
No sé muy bien cómo explicarlo así que os dejo una captura que lo muestra claramente:

```
    <!-------FEBRERO-------->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Febrero</div>
        <table id="resultados" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th>Hombres <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
                <th>Mujeres <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
            </thead>
            <?php
            foreach($usersFebrero as $user){
                $pacient  = $user->getPacient();
            ?>
            <tr>
                <?php if($pacient->gender == "h"){
                    echo "<td>".$pacient->name." ".$pacient->lastname."</td><td></td>";
                }elseif($pacient->gender == "m"){
                    echo "<td></td><td>".$pacient->name." ".$pacient->lastname."</td>";
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
    <?php
            }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

[image: Ese código muestra esto]

Sabréis a lo que me refiero, probablemente sea una tontería pero no doy con la solución. ¿Una mano?
¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola. Dime si entendí: ¿ Necesitas que mientras existan hombres o mujeres, en la consulta, no hayan celdas vacías sobre sus nombres ?

Comment: Exacto, justo eso, para que no queden huecos en blanco

Comment: Entonces, la solucíon es muy simple, puedes tener un array que recoge nombres de hombres y mujeres, y un contador de último indice usado para cada género de modo que los situas. cuando terminas recorres el array generando las líneas de la tabla

Comment: Perdona pero aunque sé lo que me dices, no termino de verlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta idea de solución está basada en tu código y en lo que te comenté hace un momento. Tiene un defecto: a la tabla no pasa información de los pacientes, de modo que no hay camino de vuelta para tratar de hacer algo con ellos cuando el usuario haga click sobre sus nombres.

**Antes de escribir la tabla organizar la consulta en una matriz**

```
<?php
// Variables para preprocesar la información dejandola lista para ser
// pasada a la tabla
$preparado = [];
$ultimo = 0;
$ultima = 0;
// recorrer la consulta para pasar los pacientes a la matriz $preparado
foreach($preparado as $user){
    $pacient = $user->getPacient();
    if($pacient->gender == "h"){
        if(!isset($preparado[$ultimo])){
            // si aún no se ha creado la línea se agrega formateada
            // para insertar espacio vacío en la celda
            $preparado[$ultimo]=['h'=>'&nbsp;', 'm'=>'&nbsp;'];
        }
        $preparado[$ultimo]['h'] = $pacient->name." ".$pacient->lastname;
        $ultimo++; // queda listo para el siguiente, si lo hay
    }else{
        if(!isset($preparado[$ultima])){
            // si aún no se ha creado la línea se agrega formateada
            // para insertar espacio vacío en la celda
            $preparado[$ultima]=['h'=>'&nbsp;', 'm'=>'&nbsp;'];
        }
        $preparado[$ultima]['m'] = $pacient->name." ".$pacient->lastname;
        $ultima++; // queda listo para la siguiente, si la hay
    }
}
?>
```

En este momento se tiene los pacientes organizados el líneas y se está listo para pasar la consulta a la tabla.
Voy a usar tu código, para que notes los cambios, porque me parece la mejor manera para que me entiendas. (No es lo que yo haría si tuviera que hacerlo, al final muestro como lo haría para mi)

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Febrero</div>
    <table id="resultados" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <th>Hombres <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
            <th>Mujeres <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        </thead>
        <?php
        foreach($preparado as $linea){
        ?>
            <tr>
            <?php 
                echo "<td>".$linea['h']."</td><td></td>";
                echo "<td>".$linea['m']."</td>";
            ?>
            </tr>
    <?php
        }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Como puedes observar ahora el ciclo de escritura de líneas se ve más simple.
Ahora como ofrecería la salida tratando de usar menos `echo` para que la página sirva más rápido. Es importante reducir la alternación de modos php y html:

```
<?php
// Paso la consulta preparada a un array de líneas listo para ser
// pasado al cuerpo de la tabla
$lineas = []; // declaro el array
foreach($preparado as $linea){
    // Fundo los dos elementos en una sóla línea pero aún no los envío
    // agregando al array líneas:
    $lineas[] = "<tr><td>".$linea['h']."</td><td></td><td>"
            .$linea['m']."</td></tr>";
}
// ahora el cuerpo de la tabla
$cuerpo = '<tbody>'.implode('', $lineas).'</tbody>;
?>
// Finalmente escribo la tabla sin ciclos internos ni anidaciónes
// que pueden provocar olvidos y errores de sintaxis
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Febrero</div>
<table id="resultados" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Hombres <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
        <th>Mujeres <i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
    </thead>
    <?php
        echo $cuerpo;
    ?>
</table>
```

Y ahora tengo la escritura de la tabla, casi sin mezcla de los dos lenguajes y sin riesgo de olvidos de sintaxis.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo entendí bien y funcionó, además lo hice a tu manera y tendré en cuenta los consejos. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Me alegra mucho! Ahora, sería bueno que aceptes la respuesta para que otros usuarios con dudas similares sepan que la pueden usar.